# Braintree Drop-In (cards & paypal) + subscriptions (PHP). Problem with paymentMethodNonce

Tags: php, paypal, subscription, braintree

I have been able to create a test check-out (js+php) in my server using the Braintree drop-in method. I need to create **subscriptions** for my customers accepting paypal or credit cards. The checkout (client-side) form is working and I *POST* it to a php page where I get the form data and create the Customer, plan, etc.

However, I have problems when creating the subscription. I get the *Cannot use a paymentMethodNonce more than once* or similar errors.

This is what I do:

1. checkout form (drop-in) submits data to *subscription.php?payload_nonce=tokencc_bc_s27k55_c7pcq8_8mvd43_xxcvvf_9p5*

> ```
> braintree.dropin.create({
>   authorization: 'sandbox_6vqkmmsy_fs5432wttyb8qpzf',
>   container: '#dropin-container',
>   locale: 'es_ES',
>   paypal: {
>   flow: 'vault'
>   }
> }, function (createErr, instance) {
>   button.addEventListener('click', function () {
>     instance.requestPaymentMethod(function (err, payload) {
>       // Submit payload.nonce to your server
>       url = 'subscription.html?payload_nonce=' + payload.nonce;
>       window.location.replace(url);
>     });
>   });
> });
> ```

2. Then in the destination page I create the Customer...

> ```
> $payload_nonce = $_GET['payload_nonce'];
>
> $result = Braintree_Customer::create(array(
>           'firstName' => $name,
>           'email' => $email,
>           'company' => $company
>       ));
> ```

3. ...his payment method...

> ```
> $resultPM = Braintree_PaymentMethod::create([
>   'customerId' => $customerId,
>   'paymentMethodNonce' => $payload_nonce
> ]);
> ```

4. ...and finally the subscription...

> ```
>     $subscriptionData = array(
>         'paymentMethodNonce' => $payload_nonce,
>         'planId' => $billingplan
>     );
>
>     $result = Braintree_Subscription::create($subscriptionData);
> ```

I have tried to add the paymentMethodNonce when creating the Customer, or when creating the paymentMethod, etc. with same results.

If the payment method is "credit card" I can get the mayment method token like this:

> 'paymentMethodToken' => $result->customer->creditCards[0]->token

But if it is PayPal there is no creditcards[0]. Which is the correct method to achieve what I need?

Thanks!

Comment: The PayPal accounts should be at `$result->customer->paypalAccounts[0]->token`. Using your current flow, would it be possible to grab the payment method token directly from the `resultPM` response? That way, you could pass the `paymentMethodToken` parameters instead of the nonce in your `Braintree_Subscription::create()` method. This would also avoid having to hardcode `creditCards` or `paypalAccounts`.

Comment: If I create the PaymentMethod using the nonce, and then I use this to get the paymentmethodToken, `$paymentmethodToken = $resultPM->paymentMethodToken;` i get an empty value.

Comment: Sorry, the correct code is `$paymentmethodToken = $resultPM->paymentMethod->token;`. Now it seems it's working with cards and paypal! Thanks!